# How to rewrite the URL

Tags: html, jsf, url-rewriting, seam, richfaces

I have a small application built using Seam 2.2, Richfaces 3.3, JBoss 5.1.

Most of the page navigation adds the request parameters to the target [URL](http://localhost:8080/books/Book.seam?userId=29&orderId=13&cmId=11cid=2). I would like to hide parameters to be hidden to the customer who is using the application (e.g. I would expect the URL to be something like "http://localhost:8080/books/Book.seam". The parameters (userId, orderId and cmId) are currently mapped to the backend bean via Book.page.xml.

How do I prevent the request parameters from showing up in the browser URL, as it also allows the customer to manipulate the URL.

We did look at seam URL re-writing feature, it talked about manipulating say the primary key id in a REST format, not sure how to accomplish something more complex like the above use case in a elegant fashion.

Comment: You're insane for using such awful bloated technologies.

Comment: check this if it helps 
http://www.jtict.com/blog/seam-form-url-rewriting/

Comment: @hendry I guess you have a lot of experience with richfaces and seam to call them 'awful bloated'?

Answer (score 4):

[PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/) offers url-rewriting for JSF.

You can't, however, 'hide' the GET parameters. Unless you make them POST parameters. But all submissions are POST in JSF by default.

Comment: We have tried prettyfaces, tuckey url re-write filters but couldn't get it to work in our environment.

We have used the web:rewrite-filter from seam and have been reasonably successful regarding the URLs which are being generated, but it becomes very complex when it is on a list page generated by EntityQuery where you have sort parameters like dir, logic, sort apart from the query parameters for running the query itself which are many in our case.

    <web:rewrite-filter view-mapping="*.seam" />

CONTINUED in the next comment

Comment: We are passing page parameters whenever we load a particular object from the list of objects generated via EntityQuery (i.e. we have many f:param declaration on a s:link pointing to the Entity itself, and these page parameters are passed in the URL. 

You have mentioned this to be made as POST parameters, how can I do this?

Comment: PrettyFaces should allow you to convert GET ?parameters into /path/parameters. It's very good at that. Or you can try http://ocpsoft.com/rewrite/