# How to create addressable pages using JSF

Tags: jsf, rest, jakarta-ee

Using the currrent version of Java EE, how do you create *addressable* web pages using Java Server Faces (JSF). That is, creating JSF pages that have a [clean URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restful_URL), so the page for the *person* entity with ID 1234 might be `http://www.example.com/person/1234`? It's clear enough to me how to service a clean URL using the [Java API for RESTful web services (JAX-RS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-RS), but not how to do so for a JSF page, or how to combine the two.

[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428418/is-restful-jsf-possible) I found suggests that doing so is not actually possible. Is that really so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a URL rewriting solution like [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/). It uses basically a simple `Filter` under the covers which [forwards](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) the request from pretty to ugly URL and [redirects](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) the request from ugly to pretty URL based on some XML mapping file.

#### Related questions:

- [Bookmarkable URL in JSF application - Trying to use Spring Webflow and JSF . Any suggestions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775884/bookmarkable-url-in-jsf-application-trying-to-use-spring-webflow-and-jsf-any)
- [How to rewrite the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052745/how-to-rewrite-the-url)
- [How do I configure JSF url mappings without file extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860004/how-do-i-configure-jsf-url-mappings-without-file-extensions)

Comment: Wow, so it is not possible do so easilly, you have to use a third party tool to do it. That sucks.

Comment: I'm not sure why that sucks. Just drop in classpath and provide a config file. That's all. But if you insist, you can also homegrow it yourself :) At least, this is not the immediate responsibility of JSF as being "just" a component based MVC framework, so nothing "out the box" is been offered. As a completely different alternative, checkout Spring MVC. It supports RESTful URLs out the box. You only have to live with a bit more parameter handling and presentation boilerplate code as it is a request based MVC framework, not a component based one.

Comment: "I'm not sure why that sucks": because JSF provides means of mapping values to URL components, but not as a clean URL, and the work-around is to translate rather than have JSF provide the functionality itself.